# Preserve LineFeeds (WIndows/Unix/Max) when pasting into a textarea

Tags: textarea, line-breaks

I cannot seem to be able to preserve the type of linebreaks when pasting Unix Linefeeds into an HTML textbox on a Windows machine.

So I have this text in Notepad++:

[image]

Pasting this into a HexEditor shows it correctly with just one single LineFeed ("0A"):
[image]

However if I paste the same into an HTML form/textarea, and then select & copy it again (Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C) and then paste it back to the HexEditor, the Linefeeds are replaced by Windows EOL (CR+LF, "0D 0A")

[image]

I can't seem to be able to submit the form with just "0A", I always end up getting "0D 0A".

I have tried all values for "white-space" CSS property of textarea.
I have tried Firefox, Chrome, Opera. I am on Windows 10.

What is happening? Who does this? How can I paste without the linebreaks changing?